# How i can access NSUserDefault of iOS project in to react native?

Tags: ios, swift, react-native

I created one project in iOS swift and created few screens in swift, now i want to use this screens in to react native so i need to access swift NSUserDefault in to react native for persistant session so how i can use it please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way just make a small native module in objc (since ReactNative SDK is objc code) in your XCode project   by adding next files:

**RNUserDefaults.h**:

```c
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RNUserDefaults : NSObject <RCTBridgeModule>
@end
```

**RNUserDefaults.m**:

```c
#import "RNUserDefaults.h"

@implementation RNUserDefaults

RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(UserDefaults)

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(set:(NSString*)key value:(id)value) {
    [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:value forKey:key];
}

RCT_EXPORT_METHOD(get:(NSString*)key callback:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)callback) {
    id value = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults objectForKey:key];
    callback(@[value]);
}

@end
```

It's much harder to to implement native module in Swift because you also should add .h and .m files to remapping (`RCT_EXTERN_REMAP_MODULE`) to swift with external declarations (`RCT_EXTERN_METHOD`).

How to use:

```js
import {
    ...
    NativeModules,
} from 'react-native';

...

NativeModules.UserDefaults.set('userId', 1234);
NativeModules.UserDefaults.get('userId', value => {
    alert(value); // Shows 1234
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store data in persistant storage like this.

Here is the sample snippet.

```
AsyncStorage.setItem('loggedIn', true);
```

And in your app.js you can check this flag in constructor

```
AsyncStorage.getItem('loggedIn').then((value) => {
        if (value) {
           //user logged in logic goes here
        } else {
         // user logged out. You need to login him again
        }
     });
```

Comment: i already setItem in iOS swift using NSUserDefault but i want to access this saved NSUserDefault  value in React native.

Comment: try `AsyncStorage.getItem` this things

Comment: its giving me Null

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use Settings from react-native it is a wrapper over `NSUserDefaults` read more [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/settings)

if you are getting null value while fetching the value what you set in the iOS native side, must check its return type is supported by the react-native bridge, if you would try to send back data type like `NSDate` it will give you null, so check the list if you need any sort of typecasting [here](https://reactnative.dev/docs/native-modules-ios#argument-types)